# How to draw grid lines that scale?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a canvas, and I want to give it grid lines as a background, but I want there to be a constant number of grid lines that divide the canvas into equally-sized sections, rather than just have equally-spaced grid-lines. I want this to be preserved when the canvas is resized by the user.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which is based in two wpf ListView controls behind the canvas(one for rows and second for columns). The content of the columns related ListView control is a rectangle.

**Updated version - Managed Grid Lines Control.** Here you can manage the number of grid lines and their visibility.

**Xaml code - grid lines control:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CAnvasWithGrid.GridLineControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:canvasWithGrid="clr-namespace:CAnvasWithGrid"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="This">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InnerListviewDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type canvasWithGrid:CellModel}">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Margin="0" StrokeDashArray="4" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" Fill="Transparent"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListviewDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type canvasWithGrid:RowModel}">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CellModels}" BorderBrush="#00FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding CellModels, Converter={canvasWithGrid:CollectionLength2NumberConverter}}"></UniformGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="0"
                                              ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InnerListviewDataTemplate}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InnerListviewDataTemplate}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=RowModels}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=RowModels, Converter={canvasWithGrid:CollectionLength2NumberConverter}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="-1"
                                              ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ListviewDataTemplate}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListviewDataTemplate}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Grid lines control - code behind**

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for GridLineControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class GridLineControl : UserControl
{
    public GridLineControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NumberOfColumns", typeof (int), typeof (GridLineControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), NumberOfColumnsChangedCallback));

    private static void NumberOfColumnsChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var numberOfRows = (int)dependencyObject.GetValue(NumberOfRowsProperty);
        var numberOfColumns = (int)args.NewValue;
        if (numberOfColumns == 0 || numberOfRows == 0) return;
        var rowModelsCollection = GetRowModelsCollection(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        dependencyObject.SetValue(RowModelsProperty, rowModelsCollection);
    }

    public int NumberOfColumns
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(NumberOfColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberOfColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfRowsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NumberOfRows", typeof (int), typeof (GridLineControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), NumberOfRowsChangedCallback));

    private static void NumberOfRowsChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var numberOfRows = (int)args.NewValue;
        var numberOfColumns = (int)dependencyObject.GetValue(NumberOfColumnsProperty);
        if(numberOfColumns == 0 || numberOfRows == 0) return;
        var rowModelsCollection = GetRowModelsCollection(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        dependencyObject.SetValue(RowModelsProperty, rowModelsCollection);
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<RowModel> GetRowModelsCollection(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        var rowModelsCollection = new ObservableCollection<RowModel>();
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            rowModelsCollection.Add(new RowModel(numberOfColumns) {Position = (i + 1).ToString()});
        }
        return rowModelsCollection;
    }

    public int NumberOfRows
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(NumberOfRowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberOfRowsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowModelsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RowModels",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<RowModel>), typeof(GridLineControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<RowModel>)));

    public ObservableCollection<RowModel> RowModels
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<RowModel>)GetValue(RowModelsProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(RowModelsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class RowModel:BaseGridMember
{
    public RowModel(int numberOfCellsInRow)
    {
        CellModels = new ObservableCollection<CellModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCellsInRow; i++)
        {
            CellModels.Add(new CellModel{Position = (i+1).ToString()});
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<CellModel>  CellModels { get; set; }
}

public class CellModel:BaseGridMember
{

}

public class BaseGridMember:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _position;

    public string Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set
        {
            _position = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main window xaml code - as you can see here is a ImageContol instead of Canvas but you can replace it:**

```
<Window x:Class="CAnvasWithGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:canvasWithGrid="clr-namespace:CAnvasWithGrid"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="525" Width="525" x:Name="This">

<Grid Tag="{Binding ElementName=This}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Bool2VisConvKey" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Show Grid Lines" Command="{Binding ShowGridLinesCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
    <Image Source="Resources/Koala.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown"/>
    <canvasWithGrid:GridLineControl NumberOfRows="50" NumberOfColumns="50" 
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=AreGridLineVisible, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisConvKey}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Main window code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowGridLinesCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowGridLineManageCommand);
        AreGridLineVisible = true;
    }

    private void ShowGridLineManageCommand()
    {
        AreGridLineVisible = !AreGridLineVisible;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AreGridLineVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AreGridLineVisible", typeof (bool), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public bool AreGridLineVisible
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(AreGridLineVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AreGridLineVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowGridLinesCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ShowGridLinesCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand ShowGridLinesCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(ShowGridLinesCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowGridLinesCommandProperty, value); }
    }



    private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**How it looks like:**
[image: Here.]

Comment: @GregRos here is updated version. now you can use the grid lines control as a UserControl. when your canvas can be up or down the grid lines, and in addition you can manage the grid lines visibility and number of rows/columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a candidate for a custom control with custom drawing. You don't really want to use multiple FrameworkElements like "Line" if you are expecting many grid-lines for performance reasons.

So you'd create a customControl GridLinesControl and overwrite the OnRender method. You can get the actual width and height of the component using the properties ActualWidth and ActualHeight, divide by the number of grid lines you want and draw lines using drawingContext.DrawLine.

The easiest way would be to add the GridLinesControl you've made underneath the canvas, taking up the same space (so it has the right ActualWidth and ActualHeight) like this:

```
<Grid>
    <myControls:GridLinesControl/>
    <Canvas ... />
</Grid>
```

So it's always underneath.